# ¿Como imprimir un documento sin necesidad de guardarlo previamente. En C#?

Tags: c#, impresión

Actualmente uso la siguiente función para imprimir:

```
 private void SendToPrinter(string filePath)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Verb = "print";
        info.FileName = filePath;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

Pero cuando llamo a la función, genero un archivo en binario, y no me queda otra opción que guardarlo en una carpeta y de ahí enviar el archivo a la función para imprimir.

Lo que deseo, es saltarme el paso de guardar el archivo en el disco. Es decir, cuando obtengo el binario, enviarlo directamente a la función e imprimir.

```
 SendToPrinter(byte[] filePath)....
```

Me gustaría como podría hacerlo, desde ya, gracias

Comment: Y por qué razón después de guardarlo en disco no lo eliminas y ya?

Comment: No es la idea, el objetivo es optimizar el proceso y no crear otro adicional, en este caso eliminar.

Comment: Entiendo lo de optimizar pero me parece que la eliminación no conlleva mucho trabajo: File.Delete(filePath);

Comment: pero no quiero estar creadno archivo, si ya tengo el binario